# How does compare-and-set work despite not using locking

Tags: java, compare-and-swap

As, mentioned [elsewhere](https://dzone.com/articles/how-cas-compare-and-swap-java), the types `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong` etc. makes use of CAS. CAS does not make use of locking rather it is very optimistic in nature. It follows these steps:

1) Compare the value of the primitive to the value we have got in hand.
2) If the values do not match it means some thread in between has changed the value. Else it will go ahead and swap the value with new value.

```
public final long incrementAndGet() 
{
    for (;;) {
        long current = get();
        long next = current + 1;
        if (compareAndSet(current, next))
          return next;
    }
}
```

Let's say two threads T1 and T2 reads the current value as 1 and both tries to increment value to 2. Now, Both thread reaches at line i.e if (`compareAndSet(current, next)`) at the same time and tries to update the value in parallel. If there is no locking mechanism then both threads should succeed and return 2. But this does not happen.

So, how does `compareAndSet` working without even acquiring lock?

Comment: Doing a minimal research usually helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap . And the real stuff is the cpu operation `cmpxchg8b / cmpxchg16b`.

Answer (score 0):

CAS use lock in multi-processor CPU. For single core processor, CAS will not use lock because CPU will execute command serially even if in multi-threads.

JVM implement CAS by using JNI in cpp calls, and cpp CAS operation will compile to CPU assemble command. So for single core multi-threads scenario, CPU will automatically schedule and pick a thread for each time. So there will not any safety issues in multi-threads.

Comment: In single core processor, context switching can happen and the other thread can enter after getting CPU time and stopping the first thread. Still its error prone if the entire operation is not locked. Although I know, CAS atomically updates V to the new value B, but only if the value in V matches the expected old value A; otherwise it does nothing. There are three operations occurred. So the question is there has to be some lock to make these operations atomic even in the case of single core

Comment: This is implement by CPU hardware architecture and in CPU scheduling level, those operations can be treated as atomic. I'm not very clear how the cache handle this in hardware level.